Why creating new user and roaming profile creation will result error logging in?
I added a new user to domain controller and I also added a profile path (roaming profile). I went to client computer and tried to login the new user, after logging in it is saying that the profile was not successful and need to logout try again. It is doing this over and over again until I delete the path from the user in domain controller then I can login the user to the machine. After successful login I can put back the profile path in domain controller and when I try to login the user again it is working fine (the roaming profile).
I followed the tutorials online but they all create roaming profiles to existing users not new users.
Error Message

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I found a solution to create bat file that updates the group policy:
gpupdate /force

and put that in group policy under users as a script when logging in. link that to the groups of users OUs.
